# Can anyone give me a hint on how to start this problem?

Tags: calculus

Show that if $a > -1$ and $b > a+1$, then the integral

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} \thinspace dx
 $
 is convergent.

Not really sure how to start I tried to integrate but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b}~dx~=~\frac\pi b\cdot\csc\bigg(a\cdot\frac\pi b\bigg)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $1 + x^b \ge x^b$, so that:

$$0 \le \int_1^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{1+x^b}dx \le \int_1^{\infty} \frac1{x^{b-a}}dx$$

The rightmost integral is convergent because $b - a > 1$.

On the other hand, note that $-a < 1$ and:

$$0 \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{1+x^b} dx \le \int_0^1 x^a dx = \int_0^1 \frac1{x^{-a}}dx$$